# Error: Network Error in app react-native with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

Well, I saw that there are many related questions, but none solved my problem.

my package.json

```
"axios": "0.18.0",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
```

my  api request

```
import Axios from "axios";

const SERVER = Axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://***.***.com.br'
});

export default SERVER;
```

and my actionReducer

```
export const register_user = ({ name, email, password, password_confirmation }) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(
            {
                type: CREATE_USER
            }
        )
        let url = "/users"
        Axios.post(`${SERVER}${url}`, {
            "user": {
                "name": name,
                "email": email,
                "password": password,
                "password_confirmation": password_confirmation
            }
        })
        .then(() => {
            Alert.alert('Registrado com sucesso!')
            registerUserSuccess(dispatch)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            registerUserError(err, dispatch)
        })
    }
}
```

The error is falling and the following error appears on the console:

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target-shim.js:818)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:574)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:388)
    at XMLHttpRequest.js:501
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:189)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:436)
    at MessageQueue.js:111
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:384)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// import Axios from "axios";

// const SERVER = Axios.create({
//   baseURL: 'https://***.****.com.br'
// });

// export default SERVER;

export const SERVER = 'https://***.****.com.br'
```

I'm not sure why, but correcting this gave crt